# makara rails gem How to add redis as cache store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rubygems

I am planning to use `makara gem` for rails application. I want to use `redis` as my cache store that will be shared between multiple server running the application.

the commands supported by makara cache are read and write. 
How can we add support for redis?